# Excel FInd and Replace Regex Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a Macro that is giving me some issue as I have no experience and no idea where to start.

All I am trying to do is create a find and replace Macro that will replace part of a string with nothing.

For example I have the following `Custom Field(Id)` and all I want the marco to do is remove everything apart from`Id`.

How can I achieve this?

**Code**

```
Sub FindReplace()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

fndList = Array("Custom field(", ")")
rplcList = Array("", "")

'Loop through each item in Array lists
For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next sht
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Is `Id` a number?

Comment: Nope Id is a string, another example would be `Custom field(Status)` where i would just want to keep `Status`

Comment: so my `Solution1` will work for both cases. You can create a VBA code that will `"Find And Replace"`  the string `Custom field(` for `nothing` and `"Find And Replace"`  the char `)` for `nothing`

Comment: I have tried that but it does nothing when i run the macro, I have updated the question with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `Find & Replace` without regex!

[image]

**Solution1:**

1. Select your data
2. Open Find & Replace module
3. Replace `"Custom Field("` for `""`
4. Replace `")"` for `""`

**Solution2:**

You can either use the formula present in [this site](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/459758-how-do-i-strip-out-all-non-numeric-characters.html) or use the VBA code posted at [this site](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/651-excel-remove-non-numeric-characters.html) to remove all the non-numeric characters out of a string.

```
Sub RemoveNotNum()
'Updateby20131129
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    xOut = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(Rng.Value)
        xTemp = Mid(Rng.Value, i, 1)
        If xTemp Like "[0-9]" Then
            xStr = xTemp
        Else
            xStr = ""
        End If
        xOut = xOut & xStr
    Next i
    Rng.Value = xOut
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, it was very helpful, however I am still having a slight issue in that when I run the Macro nothing happens? I have altered your find a replace suggestion in my code but as I said when I run it nothing changes?

Comment: Solved the issue, turns out the security level was set to high and the marcos were disabled, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Regexp / Variant array solution

Also handles situations where user selects multiple areas in the range.

```
Sub Retain()
Dim X
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCOl As Long

On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("select range", , Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
On Error GoTo 0

If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Pattern = "[^0-9]"
    .Global = True
For Each rng2 In rng1.Areas
If rng2.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    X = rng2.Value2
        For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
            For lngCOl = 1 To UBound(X, 2)
                X(lngRow, lngCOl) = .Replace(X(lngRow, lngCOl), vbNullString)
            Next
        Next
    rng2.Value2 = X
Else
   rng2.Value2 = .Replace(rng2, vbNullString)
End If
Next
End With

End Sub
```